# How to pass $q to angular directive link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I need to use `$q` a `link` function of my directive. I need it to wrap possible promise that is retuned by one of arguments (see the example below). I don't know however, how to pass `$q` dependency to a this function.

```
angular.module('directives')
 .directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     scope: {
       onEvent: '&'
     }
     // ...
     link: function($scope, $element) {
       $scope.handleEvent() {
         $q.when($scope.onEvent()) {
            ...
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got some pretty weird and probably broken syntax in that link function, by the way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add it as a dependency on your directive and the $q will be usable in the link function. This is because of JavaScript's [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Below is an example based on your code.

```
angular.module('directives')
.directive('myDirective', ['$q', function($q) {
   return {
     scope: {
       onEvent: '&'
     }
     // ...
     link: function($scope, $element) {
       $scope.handleEvent() {
         $q.when($scope.onEvent()) {
           ...
         }
       }
     }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject into the link function directly, but you *can* inject into the directive's factory function:

```
angular.module('directives')
 .directive('myDirective', function($q) {
   ...
```

Or use the array syntax for injection if you use a minifier.

Answer (score 2):

```
var module = angular.module('directives');
module.directive('myDirective', ['$q', function($q) {
 ...
}]);
```